# Work around for lack of Grouping in CompositeCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, compositecollection

When I try to add a GroupDescriptor to my CompositeCollection I get an exception informing me that the CompositeCollection does not supporting grouping.

I would like to know if anyone has found a good work around for this limitation. I have two collections which I am "zipping" together and trying to group. If it is any help, I am not interested in grouping between the collections, just with in the collections them selves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CollectionViewSource` on your `CompositeCollection`, please take a look at [How to handle a CompositeCollection with CollectionView features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079553/how-to-handle-a-compositecollection-with-collectionview-features).

Comment: CollectionViewSource on CompositeCollection does not support grouping, so how exactly does your answer solve the problem?