# Iterating through items of CompositeCollection

Tags: .net, compositecollection

Consider the code:

```
ObservableCollection<string> cities = new ObservableCollection<string>();
ObservableCollection<string> states = new ObservableCollection<string>();

ListBox list;

cities.Add("Frederick");
cities.Add("Germantown");
cities.Add("Arlington");
cities.Add("Burbank");
cities.Add("Newton");
cities.Add("Watertown");
cities.Add("Pasadena");

states.Add("Maryland");
states.Add("Virginia");
states.Add("California");
states.Add("Nevada");
states.Add("Ohio");

CompositeCollection cmpc = new CompositeCollection();
CollectionContainer cc1 = new CollectionContainer();
CollectionContainer cc2 = new CollectionContainer();

cc1.Collection = cities;
cc2.Collection = states;

cmpc.Add(cc1);
cmpc.Add(cc2);

list.ItemsSource = cmpc;

foreach(var itm in cmpc)
{
    // itm is CollectionContainer and there are only two itm’s
    // I need the strings
}
```

While list shows the right data on the GUI

I need this data (without referring to the ListBox) and I am not getting it

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `foreach (var itm in cmpc.Cast<CollectionContainer>().SelectMany(x => x.Collection.Cast<string>()))`

Comment: this will iterate for the only first level CollectionContainer  that won't get results

Comment: This is a nice trick.Isnt there a way to do it directly?
How come the ListBox sees the strings? What does it use?

Answer (score 2):

The `ListBox` uses for its `ItemsSource` Property the default view of the collection, which you can use, too:

```
  foreach (string itm in CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(cmpc))
  {
    Debug.Print(itm);
  }
```

You can use the `ICollectionView` classes to sort or filter an `ItemsSource`, but be careful while this won't work properly with `CompositeCollection`s, as you can see this question: [How to handle a CompositeCollection with CollectionView features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079553/how-to-handle-a-compositecollection-with-collectionview-features)

Answer (score 1):

you should extract data from cmpc items and set them as data source as list.ItemsSource won't understand that u need to set inner items of items as a datasource 
**EDIT**

You can use this method

```
List<string> GetData(CompositeCollection cmpc)
        {
            List<string> allStrings = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in cmpc)
            {
                allStrings.AddRange(item.OfType<string>());
            }
            return allStrings;
        }
```

and set datasource

```
list.ItemsSource = GetData(cmpc);
```

Comment: his is a nice trick.Isnt there a way to do it directly?
How come the ListBox sees the strings? What does it use?

Comment: what did you mean by directly ?

Comment: something on the  line of : foreach(var itm in cmpc)

Comment: that's already what I did in the above code ,I just make your foreach loop extract strings and return it as a datasource for ListBox  ... could you please clarify to me what you need exactly ?